# WP-Page Navi doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

How to solve this problem ? I really don't have any idea.
 Plugin generate only this html :

```
<div class="wp-pagenavi">
  <span class="pages">Page 1 of 1</span><span class="current">1</span>
</div>
```

This is my archive.php

```
   <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array(  'orderby' => 'ASC',  )); ?> 
    <?php if($loop->have_posts() ) :  ?> 

    <?php while($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 

    <article class="article">
        <div class="time"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></div>
        <div class="h2"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="article__descript">
            <?php $content = the_content();
            $test =substr($content, 0, 20);
            echo $test; ?>
        </div>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php else : ?> 
    <?php endif;  ?>
```

Comment: How many post you have added in back end?

Comment: @AftabHusain 8 post

Comment: With default settings, pagination will show when posts will greater than 10

Comment: @AftabHusain, i added a few posts, now i have 15, but doesn't work. In admin i have this : [image](https://prnt.sc/i3uapy)

Comment: I have post an answer . Try that and let me know.

Comment: @AftabHusain worked, thanks a lot )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have  updated your code- 
You have not passed the parameter `paged` in query arguments.

```
<?php 

 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

 $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post',
                                    'paged' => $paged,
                                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                                    'orderby' => 'date',
                                    'post_status'=>'publish'                               
                                    ));
 ?> 
    <?php if($loop->have_posts() ) :  ?> 

    <?php while($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 

    <article class="article">
        <div class="time"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></div>
        <div class="h2"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="article__descript">
            <?php $content = the_content();
            $test =substr($content, 0, 20);
            echo $test; ?>
        </div>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php else : ?> 
    <?php endif;  ?>
```